# Compare elements of 2D array to the product of two 1D arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, statistics, probability-density

I'm trying to compare a 2D array to the product of two 1D arrays (joint-probability density v.s. product of its individual probability densities) in order to determine if variables x and y are independent, where independence is given as `ρ(x,y)=ρ(x)*ρ(y)`.

Let's say I called the 2D array `h`, and the 1D lists `n` and `m`. How would I go about iterating over `h` to check if it's elements are equivalent to `n*m`?

Comment: Maybe construct the Cartesian product of `n` and `m` (there's probably a numpy function for it) and then look at `h` minus that product. But if you need to quantify the degree of dependence, look at mutual information. A web search should find some resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test for exact equality, just use `np.all()`

```py
import numpy as np

m = np.random.rand(10)
n = np.random.rand(20)
h = m.reshape(1, -1) * n.reshape(-1, 1)

print(np.all(h == m.reshape(1, -1) * n.reshape(-1, 1))) # True
```

To test whether the numbers are all close, you could use:

```
print(np.all(np.isclose(h, m.reshape(1, -1) * n.reshape(-1, 1))))
```